# TYPO3 Content Element: PHP Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php

I keep getting this error and I am not sure how to solve it. I have searched but none of the answers really helped me.

I went from this code:

```
$child3 !== null && strlen($child3) > 0 ? array_push($children, (int)$child3) : null;
```

To this code:

```
is_array($child3) && count($child3) > 0 ? array_push($children, (int)$child3) : null;
```

The problem still occurs and I am not sure how to solve it.

I think I still need to check for something else but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Тhe error is completely clear, you should pass string, not array. What is the error from second row ? It cannot be the same, so ?

Comment: No i mean i had the error on the first line but also on the second after i changed it

Comment: @MewTwo theres no `strlen()` in the code you posted so the error is somewhere else then. How should we help you with that? **Please read** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MewTwo In second row you don't have `strlen()` it cannot be the same error ...

Comment: if $child3 is an array, the second works, but it is better you change convert an array with (int). If $child3 is a string, the first one works. If $child3 is a string and has unicode chars, use mb_strlen instead of strlen.